# How to pass variable value to anchor attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to pass variable value to anchor attribute

```
<a href="google.com"; data-filter="red">Google.com</a>

 <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){  
        var res = "red";

        $("a[data-filter=res]");
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is variable so you need to do this way:

> If the variables are strings, the + operator concatenates them. If the variables are numbers, the + operator adds the numbers. The + operator can be used to concatenate two or more strings.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var res = "red";

    $("a[data-filter="+res+"]").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use '+' sign to concatinate variables with strings in javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var res = "red";

    $("a[data-filter='"+res+"']").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you need exactly ,
but if you want just pass the variable, try this:

```
$("a[data-filter="+res+"]").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

I think that this is what you need.